# insert Multi-line block

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

Is it possible in Visual Studio or Management Studio to paste multi-line text block inside text document?
For example my clipboard contains

```
1
2
3
4
```

my document contains

```
xxxyyy
xxxyyy
xxxyyy
xxxyyy
```

I can select space between x and y letters in diferent lines by Alt+Shift+Arrow but I cannot correctly insert my new text block. I want to see the following after insert:

```
xxx1yyy
xxx2yyy
xxx3yyy
xxx4yyy
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is.

Steps with mouse:

- Select with mouse the 1 to 4 block.
- Click copy.
- Click between x and y in the first line.
- Click paste.

Steps with keyboard:

- Navigate with arrows just before 1.
- Hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>, press 4 times <kbd>down</kbd>, one <kbd>right</kbd>, release <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
- Navigate with arrows between x and y in the first line.
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

The trick is to ensure that your clipboard doesn't contain new lines after each number. If it does, you will get something like:

```
xxx1
2
3
4yyy
xxx1
2
3
4yyy
xxx1
2
3
4yyy
xxx1
2
3
4yyy
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks!

Comment: Copying multiple lines onto your clipboard without line breaks is a trick too. For me, the lines come from SQL Server. In SSMS, I change the output to Results to Test, paste into Notepad++ with visible line breaks enabled, and then use the same SHIFT+ALT+C to copy up to but not including the visible line breaks. Then CTRL+V into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

You can

1. hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag a 4x1 rectangle around source text (1234) with mouse
2. Copy
3. hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag a 4x0 rectangle in the middle of destination text with mouse

[image]

4. Paste

You can even type after you dragged the rectangle using alt key:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the available answers worked out for me (VS 2019). I had to combine them.

1. Select the 1-4 block with holding ALT key
2. Copy
3. Place the cursor between "x" and "y" in the first line
4. Paste